# How to get a element using class and attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<ul>
      <li class="item padding-15 unread" data-id="10">
      <li class="item padding-15 unread" data-id="11">
      <li class="item padding-15 unread" data-id="12">
      <li class="item padding-15 unread" data-id="13">
      <li class="item padding-15 unread" data-id="14">
</ul>
```

How do I find a  li with class name item and data attribute id = 10?

I have tried this

```
$("li").find("[data-slide=10]");
```

But it's not working

Comment: there is no `data-slide` in your example, only `data-id`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in just one query:

```
$("li[data-id=10]")
```

Answer (score 1):

`.find` looks at children - if you want them as separate steps use `.filter`

```js
$("li").filter("[data-id=10]").css("color", "green"); 

var li = $("li");

li.filter("[data-id=12]").css("color", "blue"); 
li.filter("[data-id=13]").css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
      <li class="item padding-15 unread" data-id="10">10</li>
      <li class="item padding-15 unread" data-id="11">11</li>
      <li class="item padding-15 unread" data-id="12">12</li>
      <li class="item padding-15 unread" data-id="13">13</li>
      <li class="item padding-15 unread" data-id="14">14</li>
</ul>
```